# Set new column value based on latest record

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe which is similar to below

```
+-------+-------+----------+
|dept_id|user_id|entry_date|
+-------+-------+----------+
|      3|      1|2020-06-03|
|      3|      2|2020-06-03|
|      3|      3|2020-06-03|
|      3|      4|2020-06-03|
|      3|      1|2020-06-04|
|      3|      1|2020-06-05|
+-------+-------+----------+
```

Now I need to add a new column which should indicate the latest entry date of the user. 1 means latest, 0 means old

```
+-------+-------+----------+----------
|dept_id|user_id|entry_date|latest_rec
+-------+-------+----------+----------
|      3|      1|2020-06-03|0
|      3|      2|2020-06-03|1
|      3|      3|2020-06-03|1
|      3|      4|2020-06-03|1
|      3|      1|2020-06-04|0
|      3|      1|2020-06-05|1
+-------+-------+----------+---------
```

I tried by finding rank of the user

```
val win = Window.partitionBy("dept_id", "user_id").orderBy(asc("entry_date"))
someDF.withColumn("rank_num",rank().over(win))
```

Now stuck with how to populate the latest_rec column based on the rank_num column. How should I proceed with the next step?

Comment: Can there be multiple records with the max entry date? If so, should they all return 1?

Comment: No, there will be always one entry

Answer (score 0):

I'd use row_number to find the max date, and then derive your indicator based on that.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("dept_id", "user_id").orderBy("entry_date")

val win = <your df>.withColumn("der_rank",row_number().over(windowSpec))

val final = win.withColumn("latest_rec",when("der_rank" === 1,1).otherwise(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using rank, get the `last` when you partitionBy dept_id, user_id and orderBy entry_date, range from currentRow to unboundedFollowingRow as latest_entry_date.  Then compare entry_date with latest_entry_date and set the latest_rec values accordingly.

```
scala> df.show+-------+-------+----------+
|dept_id|user_id|entry_date|
+-------+-------+----------+
|      3|      1|2020-06-03|
|      3|      2|2020-06-03|
|      3|      3|2020-06-03|
|      3|      4|2020-06-03|
|      3|      1|2020-06-04|
|      3|      1|2020-06-05|
+-------+-------+----------+


scala> val win = Window.partitionBy("dept_id","user_id").orderBy("entry_date").rowsBetween(Window.currentRow, Window.unboundedFollowing)
win: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec = org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec@b3f21c2

scala> df.withColumn("latest_entry_date", last($"entry_date", true).over(win)).show+-------+-------+----------+-----------------+
|dept_id|user_id|entry_date|latest_entry_date|
+-------+-------+----------+-----------------+
|      3|      1|2020-06-03|       2020-06-05|
|      3|      1|2020-06-04|       2020-06-05|
|      3|      1|2020-06-05|       2020-06-05|
|      3|      3|2020-06-03|       2020-06-03|
|      3|      2|2020-06-03|       2020-06-03|
|      3|      4|2020-06-03|       2020-06-03|
+-------+-------+----------+-----------------+


scala> df.withColumn("latest_entry_date", last($"entry_date", true).over(win)).withColumn("latest_rec", when($"entry_date" === $"latest_entry_date", 1).otherwise(0)).show
+-------+-------+----------+-----------------+----------+
|dept_id|user_id|entry_date|latest_entry_date|latest_rec|
+-------+-------+----------+-----------------+----------+
|      3|      1|2020-06-03|       2020-06-05|         0|
|      3|      1|2020-06-04|       2020-06-05|         0|
|      3|      1|2020-06-05|       2020-06-05|         1|
|      3|      3|2020-06-03|       2020-06-03|         1|
|      3|      2|2020-06-03|       2020-06-03|         1|
|      3|      4|2020-06-03|       2020-06-03|         1|
+-------+-------+----------+-----------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative approach:

### Load the test data provided

```scala
   val data =
      """
        |dept_id|user_id|entry_date
        |      3|      1|2020-06-03
        |      3|      2|2020-06-03
        |      3|      3|2020-06-03
        |      3|      4|2020-06-03
        |      3|      1|2020-06-04
        |      3|      1|2020-06-05
      """.stripMargin

    val stringDS1 = data.split(System.lineSeparator())
      .map(_.split("\\|").map(_.replaceAll("""^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$""", "")).mkString(","))
      .toSeq.toDS()
    val df1 = spark.read
      .option("sep", ",")
//      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("nullValue", "null")
      .csv(stringDS1)
    df1.show(false)
    df1.printSchema()

    /**
      * +-------+-------+----------+
      * |dept_id|user_id|entry_date|
      * +-------+-------+----------+
      * |3      |1      |2020-06-03|
      * |3      |2      |2020-06-03|
      * |3      |3      |2020-06-03|
      * |3      |4      |2020-06-03|
      * |3      |1      |2020-06-04|
      * |3      |1      |2020-06-05|
      * +-------+-------+----------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- dept_id: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- user_id: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- entry_date: string (nullable = true)
      */
```

### Use max(entry_date) over(partition by 'dept_id', 'user_id')

```scala
    val w = Window.partitionBy("dept_id", "user_id")
    val latestRec = when(datediff(max(to_date($"entry_date")).over(w), to_date($"entry_date")) =!= lit(0), 0)
      .otherwise(1)
    df1.withColumn("latest_rec", latestRec)
      .orderBy("dept_id", "user_id", "entry_date")
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +-------+-------+----------+----------+
      * |dept_id|user_id|entry_date|latest_rec|
      * +-------+-------+----------+----------+
      * |3      |1      |2020-06-03|0         |
      * |3      |1      |2020-06-04|0         |
      * |3      |1      |2020-06-05|1         |
      * |3      |2      |2020-06-03|1         |
      * |3      |3      |2020-06-03|1         |
      * |3      |4      |2020-06-03|1         |
      * +-------+-------+----------+----------+
      */
```